# SQLite : insert array string into table not increased ID

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

try to insert string array into table but id for insert not increase and the first string has been insert. i use autoincreament for id?

Table Create

```
//Multi Farm Table
String CREATE_MULTI_FARM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MULTI_FARM + "(" +
        KEY_MULTI_FARM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_MULTI_FARM_FARM_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_MULTI_FARM_TABLE);
```

Insert Record Function

```
//Add Multi Farm
public void addMultiFarm(MultiFarmModel multiFarm) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_MULTI_FARM_ID, multiFarm.getId());
    values.put(KEY_MULTI_FARM_FARM_NAME, multiFarm.getFarmName());
    //Insert Record
    Log.e("StringInsertId", "" + db.insert(TABLE_MULTI_FARM, null, values));
    db.close();
}
```

Function in Class

```
public MultiFarmModel(String farmName){
    this.farmName = farmName;
}
```

Insert Code

```
String smsContent = "InsertToTable A|B|C|D|E";
DBHandler db = new DBHandler(context);
                smsContent = smsContent.substring(smsContent.indexOf(" ")+1);
                String[] string = smsContent.split("\\|");
                db.deleteAllMultiFarmRecord();
                for (String s : string) {
                    Log.e("StringToInsert", s + " ? ");
                    db.addMultiFarm(new MultiFarmModel(s));
                }
            }
```

Log Console

```
E/String Number: A|B|C|D|E
E/StringToInsert: A ? 
E/StringInsertId: 0
E/StringToInsert: B ? 
E/StringInsertId: -1
E/StringToInsert: C ? 
E/StringInsertId: -1
E/StringToInsert: D ? 
E/StringInsertId: -1
E/StringToInsert: E ? 
E/StringInsertId: -1
```

Comment: There is no need to put `values.put(KEY_MULTI_FARM_ID, multiFarm.getId());` since it will be autoincremented automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this `KEY_MULTI_FARM_ID` line because it's auto increment column... you are passing same value that's why its throwing error

```
public void addMultiFarm(MultiFarmModel multiFarm) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   // values.put(KEY_MULTI_FARM_ID, multiFarm.getId()); 
    values.put(KEY_MULTI_FARM_FARM_NAME, multiFarm.getFarmName());
    //Insert Record
    Log.e("StringInsertId", "" + db.insert(TABLE_MULTI_FARM, null, values));
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, if you want to store value of `multiFarm.getId()`, add another column in database.

Comment: yap ty its Solution